# Encryption and Decryption in Different Program

Tags: c++, rsa, crypto++

I'm trying to implement RSA Algorithm using Crypto++ under Ubuntu 12.04
I managed to implement both encryption and decryption in one program.
Is there any way so that I can separate the encryption and decryption? What I want is when I call the encryption part, it will create a ciphertext as an output, and then when I call the decryption part, it will take the ciphertext from encryption as an input, and If I call the decryption part first, then it will create an error message.

This is the code for encryption and decryption:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <iomanip>
using std::hex;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include "rsa.h"
using CryptoPP::RSA;

#include "integer.h"
using CryptoPP::Integer;

#include "osrng.h"
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    // Pseudo Random Number Generator
    AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // Generate Parameters
    CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction params;
    params.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 3072);

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // Generated Parameters
    const Integer& n = params.GetModulus();
    const Integer& p = params.GetPrime1();
    const Integer& q = params.GetPrime2();
    const Integer& d = params.GetPrivateExponent();
    const Integer& e = params.GetPublicExponent();

    cout << endl;

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    // Create Keys
    RSA::PrivateKey privateKey(params);
    RSA::PublicKey publicKey(params);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    string message, recovered;
    Integer m, c, r;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "RSA Algorithm" << endl;
    cout << "message: " ;
    std::cin >> message;

    // Treat the message as a big endian array
    m = Integer((const byte *)message.data(), message.size());
    cout << "plaintext: " << hex << m << endl << endl;

    cout << "ENCRYPTION" << endl;
    // Encrypt
    c = publicKey.ApplyFunction(m);
    cout << "cipherthext: " << hex << c << endl << endl;

    cout << "DECRYPTION" << endl;
    // Decrypt
    r = privateKey.CalculateInverse(rng, c);
    cout << "plaintext: " << hex << r << endl;

    // Round trip the message
    size_t req = r.MinEncodedSize();
    recovered.resize(req);
    r.Encode((byte *)recovered.data(), recovered.size());

    cout << "recovered: " << recovered << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: So, are you asking how to write two different programs and pipe them together?

Comment: Not that it shouldn' already be apparent, but your separate decryption will require the private key be persisted and retrieved for that purpose. Currently you're generating the key-pair on the fly. I would suggest you consider a secured key-store. Or better still, use symmetric encryption (I'm not sure there is a reason you're using RSA for this, but pipelined encryption is not really what it is made for).

Comment: @Drew yes, I want to know how to write two different program and pipe them together, but just like what WhozCraig said, I need to somehow store the encryption result and the private key for decryption, which is I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. Write two programs, each with their own main.
2. Use the `argv`you send into main to tell it what you want it to do.

For option 2, there is another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean). In essence, after checking the arg count, `argc`, and remembering argv[0] is your program, you could say

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "ENCRYPTION")==0)
{
//... do ENCRYPTION
}...
```